# lint-stage cannot see the files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lint

I've got projecct structure like below:

```
project
- .husky
- src
-- all files
- package.json
```

here is me `lint-staged` from `package.json`

```
  "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
  .
  .
  .
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run prettier",
      "npm run lint:fix"
    ]
  },
```

can someone tell me what have i'm wrong with `yarn lint-staged` that after launch this command he always return me this:

```
→ No staged files match any configured task.
```

Thanks for any help!

PS. I'm running this command from pre-push husky script

Comment: you have probably not changed anything within your js/ts codes, as lint-staged is configured to only look for those files via `*.{js,ts,tsx}` pattern. so if you've staged changes in other files, lint-staged will simply skip running.

Comment:  This was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `git add .` before running `yarn lint-staged`?

Comment: yes, always ///

Comment: Well, this script should be run on pre-commit.
If you run it on pre-push, your files are now more staging because they are in a commit