# Lint Staged: No staged files match any configured task

Tags: reactjs, eslint, husky, lint-staged

I have a react js application where i added husky with lint-staged. This is my lint staged config inside package.json file:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js, ts, tsx}": [
      "yarn format"
    ]
  },
```

NOTE: if i run `yarn lint-staged` i get `No staged files match any configured task.`, but if i run `yarn format` then it works.

If somebody faced this problem, why i get this error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was related to lint staged configuration, i just removed the spaces after file extension:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "yarn format"
    ]
  },
```

This works fine.

Comment: Surprisingly I still get no matches.

Comment: Ahh: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747518/lint-stage-cannot-see-the-files#comment136564158_70747518